# How to use a for loop inside an echo statement which is used to print statements into another script in UNIX

Tags: shell-script, solaris

My shell script contains a function which is used to print statements to another shell script

```
function print()
{
    echo "
    insert()          #insert function
    for i in $InsertFile1
    do
        cat $i
    done
    echo \""Exit--------------------------0"\"
    switch($input)
    {
        case 1 :
        ......
        ......
        default :
    }
    " > Script.sh
}
```

The variable $InsertFile1 = file1.txt and contents of file1.txt is as follows :

```
insert()          #insert function
echo "1 Start"
echo "2 Stop"
echo "3 Exit"
switch($input)
{
    case 1 :
    ......
    ......
    default :
}
```

The expected output should in Script.sh should be the contents of variable $InsertFile1
but my output (i.e. content of Script.sh) is

```
insert()          #insert function
for i in echo "1    Start"
echo "2 Stop"
echo "3 Exit"
switch($input)
{
    case 1 :
    ......
    ......
    default :
}
```

How do I skip the printing of for loop in file Script.sh ?
edit : The function print contains several other statements which needs to be included in Script.sh.

Comment: Are you trying to loop over the *contents* of the file? If so, why not simply `cat "$InsertFile1" > Script.sh` and then append the `"Exit ... "` line? A loop seems superfluous here.

Comment: The function contains other statements above and below the loop which also needs to be included in the Script.sh

Comment: In which case you need to append the contents of the file (`>>` instead of `>`) - regardless of whether you use a loop or not. I suggest you step back and describe what you actually want to achieve, rather than focusing on a specific implementation - see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @steeldriver The question has been edited now I hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function print()
    {

    for i in $InsertFile1
    do
    cat $i 
    done > Script.sh
    echo "Exit--------------------------0" >> Script.sh

    }
```

- you may wish to skip line with echo Exit
- if $Insertfile1 have only one value, script could be further simplified

  ```
  function print()
  {

  cp $Inserfile   Script.sh

  echo "Exit--------------------------0" >> Script.sh

  }
  ```